# APScheduler listener, don't work asyncio.ensure_future

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, python-asyncio, apscheduler

Tell me, where I am wrong? I create a `TornadoScheduler` in the context of a `Tornado` server. Assign a listener and a execute function. But I get not exactly what I need.

```
from tornado.concurrent import return_future, run_on_executor

class Users:
    @return_future
    @run_in_executor
     def save(self, callback=None):
         some code
         callback(some data)

scheduler.add_listener(_scheduler_listener, apscheduler.events.EVENT_ALL)

......

async def processing(event: JobEvent):
    data = await Users.get_all_users()  <-- comunicate with DB
    if isinstance(data.result(), Exception):
        raise data.result()
    .....
    done = await users.save() <-- comunicate with DB
    .....

def _scheduler_listener(event: JobEvent):
    asyncio.ensure_future(processing(event))
```

The scheduler starts the task and all 3 events with the code 512 - added, 32768 - submitted and 4096 - executed come to the listener, but it `asyncio.ensure_future()` performed only 2 times, when 512 and 32768 codes.
I use `Tornado 5`, `TornadoScheduler`. When I create a job, the scheduler sends code 512 to the listener, then code 32768 and then code 4096. But, when code 4096 arrives, asyncio.ensure_future is not executed. When I press `Crtl+C` the console is displayed:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'processing' was never awaited
2019-01-30 19:04:24,473 - asyncio - ERROR - Task was destroyed but it is pending! task: <Task pending coro=<processing() running at ....
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Please provide a self contained example. From this snippet it's hard to figure out any problems you might be having.

Comment: @Alex Grönholm I updated the question a bit, now I think it's a matter of what it is. most likely I am doing something wrong

Comment: @Alex Grönholm When I create a new event loop(**asyncio.new_event_loop()**) in **ThreadPoolExec().submit(loop.run_forever())**, and execute **asyncio.ensure_future(coro, loop=new created loop)** in it, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To run async functions, you must use AsyncIOScheduler and declare your callable as a (native) coroutine function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you give a small example of how to do this?

Comment: Looking again at this, my answer seems a bit premature. I do not know why processing(event) is not run as a task, and from that code there is no way to determine the problem. That is why I asked you to provide a self contained example – so we wouldn't have to go back and forth asking gradually more questions.

Comment: Just write a trivial module, runnable by anyone, that demonstrates the problem.